# How can I make xdebug use cookie instead of $_GET parameters?

Tags: php, xdebug

Zend debugger uses cookie as debugging flag,how can I make it the same for xdebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session

It says:

> When there is a GET (or POST) variable
>   XDEBUG_SESSION_START **or the
>   XDEBUG_SESSION cookie is set,** Xdebug
>   will try to connect to a debugclient.